# Dynamic tests fail with failed to exit gracefully

Tags: jestjs, feathersjs

I have a javascript feathers application in which I'm making a test to verify my database structure compared to the sequelize models. I have been able to create the starting point, checking if a table exists, but now want to loop through the columns. How ever if I run my test I get this output:
``` ● 02. Data structure › 01. Tables › 01. Tables required exist › Table `sys_custom_objects` should exist

````
Tests cannot be nested. Test "Column `description` should exist" cannot run because it is nested within "Table `sys_custom_objects` should exist".

  52 |                             const oCheckColumn = Lodash.find(oColumns, { column_name: oColumn.field});
  53 | 
> 54 |                             it('Column `' + oColumn.field + '` should exist', () => {
     |                             ^
  55 |                                 expect(oCheckColumn.length).toBe(1);
  56 |                             });
  57 |                         });```
````

Currently my test file is as follows:

```
const Lodash = require('lodash');
const App = require('../../../src/app');
const seqClient = App.get('seqClient');

const MODELS = seqClient.models;
const oModels = [];

Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
    oModels.push(oModel);
});

describe('02. Data structure', () => {
    describe('01. Tables', () => {
        describe('01. Tables required exist', () => {
            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, async (oModel) => {
                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const strSql = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                it('Table `' + strTableName + '` should exist', () => {
                    return seqClient.query(strSql, { raw: true }).then(oTable => {
                        expect(oTable[0].length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        describe('02. Tables have the correct column definition', () => {
            let iCount = 0;

            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, async (oModel) => {
                iCount += 1;

                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const oDefinedColumns = oModel.getColumns();
                const iCountColumns = Object.keys(oModel.getColumns()).length;
                const iTotalColumns = iCountColumns + 3;
                const strSql = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                describe((iCount <= 9 ? ('0' + iCount) : iCount) + '. ' + strTableName, () => {
                    it('Table `' + strTableName + '` should have `' + iTotalColumns + '` columns', () => {
                        return seqClient.query(strSql, { raw: true }).then(oResults => {
                            const oColumns = oResults[0];

                            expect(oColumns.length).toBe(iTotalColumns);
                        });
                    });

                    return seqClient.query(strSql, { raw: true }).then(oResults => {
                        const oColumns = oResults[0];

                        Lodash.forEach(oDefinedColumns, (oColumn) => {
                            const oCheckColumn = Lodash.find(oColumns, { column_name: oColumn.field });

                            it('Column `' + oColumn.field + '` should exist', () => {
                                expect(oCheckColumn.length).toBe(1);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I think I need some help with putting a `await`  in the code for it seems as if now it seems as if things are getting mixed up. Any advice?

Edit 1.
So i changed my test file and now it does the tests. I still need to add more too. Right now it will do 786 tests in 7 seconds. This is the new file.

```
const App = require('../../../src/app');
const seqClient = App.get('seqClient');

const MODELS = seqClient.models;
const oModels = [];

Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
    oModels.push(oModel);
});

describe('02. Data structure', () => {
    describe('01. Tables', () => {
        describe('01. Tables required exist', () => {
            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const strSql = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                it('Table `' + strTableName + '` should exist', async () => {
                    const oTable = await seqClient.query(strSql, { raw: true });
                    const oColumns = oTable[0];

                    expect(oColumns.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                });
            });
        });

        describe('02. Tables have the correct column definition', () => {
            let iCount = 0;

            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
                iCount += 1;

                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const oDefinedColumns = oModel.getColumns();
                const iCountColumns = Object.keys(oModel.getColumns()).length;
                const iTotalColumns = iCountColumns + 3;
                const strSqlTable = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                describe((iCount <= 9 ? ('0' + iCount) : iCount) + '. ' + strTableName, async () => {
                    it('Table `' + strTableName + '` should have `' + iTotalColumns + '` columns', async () => {
                        const oTable = await seqClient.query(strSqlTable, { raw: true });
                        const oColumns = oTable[0];

                        expect(oColumns.length).toBe(iTotalColumns);
                    });

                    Lodash.forEach(oDefinedColumns, (oDefinedColumn) => {
                        const strSqlColumn = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\' and column_name = \'' + oDefinedColumn.field + '\'';

                        it('Column `' + oDefinedColumn.field + '` should exist', async () => {
                            const oColumn = await seqClient.query(strSqlColumn, { raw: true });

                            expect(oColumn[0].length).toBe(1);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I now have to questions to answer/solve:

1. I'm getting `A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.` in the out put which I would like to have solved
2. The SQL for the column checks would preferably be executed once per table, this because it returns all columns, and the next tests will be on datatype/length etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have the cycle now running. I added a `beforeAll` within the corresponding `describe`. If the the `table` is still empty, it executes my sql statement. This format reduced the same test by 2 seconds (7 to 5). It now is:

```
const Lodash = require('lodash');
const App = require('../../../src/app');
const seqClient = App.get('seqClient');

const MODELS = seqClient.models;
const oModels = [];

Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
    oModels.push(oModel);
});

describe('02. Data structure', () => {
    describe('01. Tables', () => {
        describe('01. Tables required exist', () => {
            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const strSql = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                it('Table `' + strTableName + '` should exist', async () => {
                    const oTable = await seqClient.query(strSql, { raw: true });
                    const oColumns = oTable[0];

                    expect(oColumns.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                });
            });
        });

        describe('02. Tables have the correct column definition', () => {
            let iCount = 0;

            Lodash.forEach(MODELS, (oModel) => {
                iCount += 1;

                const strTableName = App.get('oTables')[oModel.name];
                const oDefinedColumns = oModel.getColumns();
                const iCountColumns = Object.keys(oModel.getColumns()).length;
                const iTotalColumns = iCountColumns + 3;
                const strSqlTable = 'select column_name, udt_name, is_nullable, character_octet_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = \'' + strTableName + '\'';

                describe((iCount <= 9 ? ('0' + iCount) : iCount) + '. ' + strTableName, () => {
                    let oTable = null;
                    let oColumns = null;

                    beforeAll(async () => {
                        if (oTable === null) {
                            oTable = await seqClient.query(strSqlTable, { raw: true });
                            oColumns = oTable[0];
                        }
                    });

                    it('Should have `' + iTotalColumns + '` columns', () => {
                        expect(oColumns.length).toBe(iTotalColumns);
                    });

                    Lodash.forEach(oDefinedColumns, (oDefinedColumn) => {
                        it('Column `' + oDefinedColumn.field + '` should exist', () => {
                            const oColumn = Lodash.find(oColumns, { column_name: oDefinedColumn.field });

                            expect(oColumn).not.toBeNull();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```